# C# How to base64 encode background gradient

Tags: c#, css

I've built a CSS generator app where a user can select two stops of a gradient and it will spit out the corresponding CSS.  I'm using the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) app as a guide.  Here is the CSS it spits out for a #1e5799 -> #7db9e8 gradient with IE9 support:

```
background: #1e5799;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzFlNTc5OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM3ZGI5ZTgiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 );
```

As you can see, all of the styles I can easily replace the HEX color codes with the exception of the second which uses base64 encoding for IE9 support.  Since this app is in C#, I need to figure out how to get the base64 encoded `data` string to use in this style.  I've found links how to do it when there is an actual image in memory or on the file system, but this isn't an image, it's a gradient.

I need to know how, in C#, I can take the two gradients stops (#1e5799 and #7db9e8 in the example's case) and spit out the following:

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

UPDATE: Here is the code I came up with for posterity:

```
    public string GetGradientCss(string topColor, string bottomColor)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLineFormat("background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,{0};", GetBase64EncodedBackground(topColor, bottomColor));
    }

    private string GetBase64EncodedBackground(string topColor, string bottomColor)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>");
        builder.Append("<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" viewBox=\"0 0 1 1\" preserveAspectRatio=\"none\">");
        builder.Append("  <linearGradient id=\"grad-ucgg-generated\" gradientUnits=\"userSpaceOnUse\" x1=\"0%\" y1=\"0%\" x2=\"100%\" y2=\"0%\">");
        builder.AppendFormat("    <stop offset=\"0%\" stop-color=\"{0}\" stop-opacity=\"1\"/>", topColor);
        builder.AppendFormat("    <stop offset=\"100%\" stop-color=\"{0}\" stop-opacity=\"1\"/>", bottomColor);
        builder.Append("  </linearGradient>");
        builder.Append("  <rect x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" fill=\"url(#grad-ucgg-generated)\" />");
        builder.Append("</svg>");
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: Well it's still a base64 representation of a byte array - which in this case is some SVG by the looks of it. So do you *have* that SVG content?

Comment: Can you clarify what you need? If you base64 decode the URI you will get some XML containing the SVG instructions ...

Comment: @JonSkeet: The input into the generator is only the two HEX color codes.  I'm not sure what that tool is using to base64 encode.  Perhaps that's the heart of my question.

Comment: @im1dermike: Well it's doing far more than a base64 encode. It's first generating the SVG, then base64-encoding *that*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is very simple SVG file (XML) that specifies gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <linearGradient id="grad-ucgg-generated" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1e5799" stop-opacity="1"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8" stop-opacity="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#grad-ucgg-generated)" />
</svg>
```

So steps to take:

- generate valid XML above with your colors (`XDocument` or LINQ-to-XML)
- save xml to a `MemoryStream`
- convert stream's `.ToArray()` to Base64
- construct the Uri. (even string  concatenation would be ok, but try `UriBuilder`)

Comment: Thanks!!  This should do it.

Comment: Or just use a template string with the two parameters (the two hex values) and then `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)` and base64 encode that.

Comment: only @JonSkeet can create valid XML with string concatenation/Format :)... But indeed in this case it would be ok.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yeah, I really wouldn't *normally* suggest it. But when the only values to be replaced are this well-known, it seems a simple solution :)

Comment: @im1dermike: Well I'd suggest using `string.Format` with a verbatim string literal (probably using `'` instead of `"` everywhere for simplicity) - much clearer than a bunch StringBuilder calls, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Agreed.  Until I get confirm the output, though, it's more readable now.

Comment: Hmm even though my code returns a different base64 string, it decodes to the same XML.

Comment: @im1dermike - could be a lot of things - like BOM in the beginning of the stream, spaces vs. tabs, ... As long it is valid XML and browser able to read it such differences should not matter.